# Fixed position on webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having issues with a fixed position on webkit browsers. It works perfectly on Firefox.
I've tried many things but I can't get to solve the problem.

Look at it here: http://vitu.me/pro/

If you click on a project a `jQuery .load()` will load a page, on this page there are the project images and **arrow** buttons and a **X** on the top. Those buttons are supposed to be fixed on the place when the page is scrolled, but it won't happen.

I hope someone can help me on this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Please provide the code where the issue is occuring in order to make it much easier for people to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You `super-janela` div is absolutely positioned. That is why your `fixed` positioned controls "don't work". Take them out of the absolutely positioned `div` or change `super-janela` position to `relative`.

Comment: Yeah, can't I have a fixed element inside an absolute one? Which browser is rendering it correctly, webkit or gecko?